# Zxing - Dynamically changing the barcode types scanned for

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I'm building a demo barcode scanning application and have gotten on pretty well.

I am using the `ContinuousCaptureActivity` example so I can have a scan window, scan options and the resultant barcode results all on 1 activity.

I have it working really well but I would like to be able to change the barcode types looked for dynamically.

I know how to do this using the `Intent` system way of doing it but this I believe is only used when you call up a built in Zxing barcode layout, however in this case I am doing everything on the same custom window so I need to be able to do things in code when I set an Android switch to "ON"

I read that the `CaptureManager` object can work in this way but I've spent days on this, but I wasn't able to achieve my goal... Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You should add some code, what did you try exacly, etc.

Comment: OK, cool, so I am using 1 activity only with a compoundView on that form.  I start the scanner with the following code:            barcodeView.decodeSingle(callback); and have a callback on the same activoty that handles the result.  I just want to be able to tell the barcodeView to not scan 2D codes but in java in the same activity somehow.  Does that  make sense?

Comment: You can edit your post to add more information, you don't need to put long text in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I worked it out finally.  I noticed that you can initialize the BarcodeView with an intent, so I tried this:

IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);

intent = integrator.createScanIntent();

barcodeView.initializeFromIntent(intent);

This will start up the barcode scanner with the desired barcode filter.